# Trying to access ModelForm field modelChoice choices in Django template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm generating ModelForms and want some granular control over how they are output in my template. Specifically, I need to add some markup to the end of each radio button in each of my select lists.

Code:

```
# order-form.html

{% load catname %}
<form id = "order-form">
{% for form in forms %}
<div id="gun-{{ forloop.counter }}">
    {% for field in form.fields %}
        <div id="{{ field }}-item" class="item">
            <h3>{{ field|catname }}</h3>
            {% for choice in form.field.choices %} {# <-- Help me out here #}
                {{ choice.id }}
                {{ choice.title }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit" id="standard-gun-form-submit">Continue to next step</button>
</form>

# views.py
def get_form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['gun_type'] == 'standard':
            forms = [StandardGunForm(prefix=p) for p in range(0,2)]
            return render_to_response('main/order-form.html', {'forms' : forms,}, RequestContext(request))

# forms.py

class StandardGunForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StandardGunForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)  
        for field in self.fields: 
            if isinstance(self.fields[field], ModelChoiceField):
                self.fields[field].empty_label = None

    class Meta:
        model = BaseGun
        widgets = {
            'FrameTuning' : RadioSelect(),
            'FrameConnection' : RadioSelect(),
        }
        exclude = ('price')
```

Endgame: markup that looks like this

```
<form id="foo">
<div class="category">
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="srsbzns" value="1">Option 1</input>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150">
        <p>Other foo here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="srsbzns" value="2">Option 2</input>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150">
        <p>Other foo here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <input type="radio" name="srsbzns" value="3">Option 3</input>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150">
        <p>Other foo here</p>
    </div>  
</div>
</form>
```

From the shell, this returns what I want

```
>>> forms = [StandardGunForm(prefix=p) for p in range(0,2)]\
>>> forms[0].fields['frame_tuning'].choices.queryset
```

I'm surprised this is proving so challenging!

Bonus: I have DEBUG = True and Django Debug toolbar enabled. Is it possible to dump the variables to the browser, so I can see what this stuff looks like as I drill down?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess `{% for id, title in field.choices %}`, but why not just `{{ field }}` with a custom widget? If you need custom output, write a custom widget... :-)

Comment: Yes, a custom widget may be the way

Answer (score 4):

I had to do something similar and started down this path as well. I wanted to create table rows from a ModelChoiceField where each column had a different field of the model instance (and then I'd allow filtering the table rows via JavaScript).

I couldn't find it in the Django docs, but a quick perusal of the Django source showed the way. You can get to the queryset to access the model instances like so:

```
<form action="{% url 'some_view' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    {% endif %}

    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.label }}

        {% if field.field.choices %}
          {% for model_instance in field.field.choices.queryset %}
            {{ model_instance.id }}
          {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
          {{ field }}
        {% endif %}

        {% if field.errors %}
            {{ field.errors|striptags }}
        {% endif %}

    {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, at this point we've disassembled the shiny widget (in my case a CheckboxSelectMultiple) and must re-assemble the HTML form input using template code. I found no direct way to simultaneously iterate over the ModelChoiceField to access the model instance fields and get the HTML form tags for the choices.

Maybe there's a way, but I abandoned my attempt and built my own HTML form, handling all the POST data in a view. It ended up much easier that way. ModelForms are really nice and convenient, but using them for something they weren't built for can end up being more difficult.

I figured I'd post this in case anyone is trying to do it for some other reason. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Very late, but I'm reading now and this is what it worked for me

```html
{% for field in form %}
  {% for x, y in field.field.choices %}
    {{x}}
    {{y}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Where "x" is the id or code, and "y" is the readable value or title.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the underlying model instance for each choice:

```
{% for choice, label in form.field_name.field.choices %}
    {{ choice.value }}
    {{ choice.instance }} 
    {{ choice.instance.instance_attribute }}
    {{ label }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for choice in form.field.choices %} {# <-- Help me out here #}
            {{ choice.id }}
            {{ choice.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Look what you're doing here, you're literally trying to access a field called "field" every time in this loop, which presumably does not exist.

You need to take the field object you're iterating through, and access the choices attribute on that.

```
{% for field in form.fields %}
   {% for choice in field.choices %}
```

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work either. I tried many many combinations before posting here. I imagine I will simply write a custom widget and generate my markup there.

Comment: starsinmypockets, try field.field.choices